# Filter support for regex or wildcards

Tags: feature-request, filter

Filter would be significantly more useful it it supported Regex or wildcards.  Ideally under a different parameter.  Wildcard could be with the * or the %.  This would allow for "starts-with" or "ends-with" type queries.  For example: wildcard=java% or wildcard=*java

Answer (score 2):

I personally think that this would be more trouble than it's worth - and I'm speaking about the **tremendous** amount of work that the API maintainers would have to go through to filter malicious RegEx queries.

...and not only malicious, but also queries that would take a long time to parse/execute.

I think that if a web giant like Google doesn't support wildcard/RegEx, there's no need for StackOverflow to support it.

Comment: Maybe just wildcard then.  Like I said, most self respecting databases support LIKE and %.